# 'Create procedure' must be only statement in batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CleanupJob
    @NoDays int = 800
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @JobStartDateTime DATETIME = getutcdate()
    --Clean records older than 800 days 
    DECLARE @rowcount int

    SELECT @rowcount = 1

    WHILE @rowcount > 0 
    BEGIN
        DELETE top (100) [DB].[INSTANCE].[TABLE_DETAIL]
        WHERE [Event_ID] IN (SELECT [Event_ID] 
                             FROM [DB].[INSTANCE].[TABLE]
WHERE start_time <  DATEADD(day, -@NoDays, @JobStartDateTime)  
)


        SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
    END
END
GO
```

It throws this error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CleanupJob, Line 14 [Batch Start
>   Line 19]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

I am not sure how to use the subquery in delete statement under proc propely.

EDIT -

**start_time** column is in **[TABLE]**

Comment: you have 2 `WHERE` in your delete statement, I guess the second should be `AND` in stead of `WHERE`

Comment: replace second 'WHERE' with AND

Comment: That closing bracket after [DB].[INSTANCE].[TABLE] in the subquery looks questionable

Comment: Is the `start_time` condition meant to be against `TABLE`? (In which case the bracketing is wrong) or against `TABLE_DETAIL` (in which case the `where` clause was already started two lines earlier)

Comment: Your subject has nothing to do with your problem either. Are you having the issue you made the subject about too?

Answer (score 3):

> but I am still getting the CREATE PROCEDURE must be only statement
>   error

Add `GO` before your `create proc`.
It seems that you have an additional code above your procedure.

Note this is not an error it's just parser highlightning.

If now you select and execute only `create proc` code it will not give you this error

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
WHILE @rowcount > 0 
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (100) [DB].[INSTANCE].[TABLE_DETAIL]
    WHERE [Event_ID] IN (
        SELECT [Event_ID] 
        FROM [DB].[INSTANCE].[TABLE]
        WHERE [start_time] <  DATEADD(day, -@NoDays, @JobStartDateTime)  

    SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

**Edit: Complete answer**

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE CleanupJob
    @NoDays int = 800
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @JobStartDateTime DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()
    DECLARE @rowcount int = 1

    WHILE @rowcount > 0 
    BEGIN
        DELETE TOP (100) [DB].[INSTANCE].[TABLE_DETAIL]
        WHERE [Event_ID] IN (
            SELECT [Event_ID] 
            FROM [DB].[INSTANCE].[TABLE]
            WHERE [start_time] <  DATEADD(day, -@NoDays, @JobStartDateTime)  

        SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
    END  
GO
```

Comment: This did fix the SQL but I am still getting the `CREATE PROCEDURE must be only statement` error

Comment: @PirateX What about now?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
DELETE A 
FROM [DB].[INSTANCE].[TABLE_DETAIL] A
where A.[Event_ID] IN 
             (SELECT [Event_ID] FROM [DB].[INSTANCE].[TABLE])
AND A.start_time <  DATEADD(day, -@NoDays,@JobStartDateTime)
```

You can add the TOP hint in this query.